# Escaping generated HTML that onclick has a jQuery function with CSS attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have mechanism that generates HTML in JavaScript, and I need to extend this mechanism to add a remove row button.

The row-generating mechanism looks like the following:

```
debug.createOverrideRow = function (override) {

    var rowStr = "";
    if (override.AutoDisplay) {
        rowStr += "<tr session-key=\"" + override.SessionKey + "\" ";
    } else {
        rowStr += "<tr class=\"hide\" session-key=\"" + override.SessionKey + "\" ";
    }
    rowStr += "session-key-data-type=\"" + override.DataType + "\">";
    rowStr += "<td id=\"tdDisplayName" + i + 1 + "\">" + override.DisplayName + "</td>";
    rowStr += "<td id=\"tdValue" + i + 1 + "\">";

    switch (override.DataType) {
        case "NullableInteger":
        case "Integer":
        case "rowString":
            rowStr += "<input type=\"text\" onChange=\"common.validateField(this, " + override.ValidationPattern + ")\" onBlur=\"common.validateField(this, " + override.ValidationPattern + ")\" />";
            break;
        case "Array":
            rowStr += "<input type=\"text\"/>";
            break;
        case "Date":
            rowStr += "<input class=\"datePicker\" placeholder=\"yyyy-mm-dd\" type=\"text\" onChange=\"common.validateDate(this)\" onBlur=\"common.validateDate(this)\" />";
            break;
        case "Boolean":
            rowStr += "<input type=\"checkbox\"/>";
            break;
        case "Radio":
            var inputs = override.InputList.split(";");
            rowStr += "<div>";
            for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                var elements = inputs[j].split(":");
                rowStr += "<input id=\"rad" + j + "\" name=\"" + override.SessionKey + "\" type=\"radio\" value=\"" + elements[0] + "\" />&nbsp;" + elements[1] + "&nbsp;";
            }
            rowStr += "</div>";
            break;
    }

    rowStr += "</td>";
    rowStr += "</tr>";
    return rowStr;
}
```

The mechanism that is supposed to inject a remove button:

```
debug.injectRemoveButtonIntoOverrideRow = function (override, row) {
    $(row).find('td:last').append("<input type=\"button\" value = \"Remove\" onClick=\"$('tr[session-key=\"" + override.SessionKey + "\"]').remove();\" />");
}
```

HTML sample:

```
<tr session-key="data.SampleId" session-key-data-type="NullableInteger"><td id="tdDisplayName71">Sample Id</td><td id="tdValue71"><input type="text"><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="$(" tr[session-key="data.SampleId" ]').remove();'=""></td></tr>
```

**Is it possible to escape the quotes so this would work?**

Comment: Why don't you just use `addEventListener`?

Comment: what are you trying to do here `onclick="$(" tr[session-key="data.SampleId" ]').remove();'=""`

Comment: Could also just transverse the DOM as you only removing the parent tr, that would mean no quote in your jquery code.

Comment: A mix of ' and " quotes and some uses of + should be enough to make the HTML string valid. Or do the sensible thing and just give your function a name, place the SampleId as a data-value and just use the name of the function. Or even better, addEventListener after the append. Perfect example why inline scripts are annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Shilly's suggestion, I have moved the selector into a function:

```
debug.injectRemoveButtonIntoOverrideRow = function (override, row) {
    var cleanedSessionKey = override.SessionKey.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
    $(row).find('td:last').append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function remove" + cleanedSessionKey + "(){ $('tr[session-key=\"" + override.SessionKey + "\"]').remove(); }</script><input type=\"button\" value = \"Remove\" onClick=\"remove"+cleanedSessionKey+"()\" />");
}
```